# How is it possible to have a Task that RanToCompletion but also Result.Status is Faulted?

Tags: task-parallel-library, async-await

I have this strange situation at the moment. I have a `Task` within which I am throwing an exception. The `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event fires but the `UnobservedException` is never rethrown (even with `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"`). When I check in the debugger I see the `Task` looks like so:

[image: RanToCompletion but also Status Faulted]

This seems suspicious to me. How can it have `RanToCompletition` but also have a `Faulted` `Result`? The exception inside the result is the one I'm throwing, but it's not making it to the `Task.Exception` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you have a `Task<Task>`. The outer `Task` ran to completion and its `Result` is another `Task`, this time a faulted one.

That's exactly what the debugger shows: the “Result” line is not some special line containing summary of the whole object, it's [the `Result` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468).

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say how the `Task<Task>` was created. But a relatively common situation in C# 5.0 is if you run an `async` method using `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. If that's the case, you should either call the `async` method directly, or, if you want to run it on a background thread, use `Task.Run()`, which automatically unwraps the `Task<Task>` into a simple `Task`.

Comment: I suspect you are onto something with the async method in Tast.Factory.StartNew... the overload takes an Action but gave no indication it would create a Task<Task>!

Comment: @Schneider That's exactly it, it has overloads for `Action` (which returns `Task`) and `Func<T>` (which returns `Task<T>`). When you call it with an `async` lambda, the `Func<T>` overload is used with `T` being `Task`, so it returns `Task<Task>`.